# How to set system variable in Netbeans

Tags: java, environment-variables, netbeans-platform

I am beginner with Java and Netbeans 8.0 IDE

I have a standalone program with the following command :

```
String p2 = System.getenv("USERPARAMETER");
```

How I can set this system variable in Netbeans 8.0 IDE ??

( In Eclipse this can be done with  " Run Configurations  " ).

Answer (score 0):

You can set and get system variable

```
//  For setting system variable

 String p2 = System.getProperty("USERPARAMETER");

// For getting system variable value

System.setProperty("ABC");
```